# Like ConcurrentBag in c# what are the options available in cpp(MFC)?

Tags: c++, mfc

C# has [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) to add and retrieve data in parallel

```
ConcurrentBag<String> profilingData = new ConcurrentBag<String>();
```

What are the options available in MFC to do the same? I have limitations to use MFC only.

Comment: "MFC _only_" sounds painful. Are no standard library functions or classes allowed?

Comment: I don't think there is something like that in MFC, but [Parallel containers and objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/parallel-containers-and-objects?view=vs-2019#queue) from Microsofts PPL (Parallel Patterns Library) may be allowed? The `concurrent_queue` looks similar to .NETs ConcurrentBag.

Comment: I have limitation of using MFC libraries only as my project has to be compiled using MFC.

Comment: Using MFC doesn't automatically exclude the standard library or other Microsoft libraries such as PPL. Good libraries can co-exist. You can use the standard library and MFC at the same time and I'm guessing that PPL can be used with MFC too.